# Error in cv2.imread(): (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() - what is wrong?

Tags: python, opencv

I have used following code to detect the big-blob but I am getting an error, how may I resolve it? the error is present at last line of the code

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np;

    # Read image
    im = cv2.imread("'C:/Data/frame2.jpg'", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Set up the detector with default parameters.
    detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create()

    # Detect blobs.
    keypoints = detector.detect(im)

    # Draw detected blobs as red circles.
    # cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS ensures the size of the circle corresponds to the size of blob
    im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

    # Show keypoints
    cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

---

**Error:**

```
    Error : im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
    cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.5) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np;

# Read image (fixed path)
im = cv2.imread("C:/Data/frame2.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

if not im:      # always check for None
    raise ValueError("unable to load Image")
```

---

**Reason for the error:**

The command `m = cv2.imread("'C:/Data/frame2.jpg'", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` can result in `im` being `None` if the image was not loaded correctly.

This is what the error tells you when calling cvtColor:

```
(-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

Check the `im` - if `None` do not proceed but check your paths and why it is not loaded correctly.

Documentation:

- [cv2.imread()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html)

with a big, red box telling you:

> Even if the image path is wrong, it won’t throw any error, but `print img` will give you `None`.